# Using \input in a fancyvrb verbatim environment - problem with hyphens

Tags: verbatim, input

I've set up a custom environment with `DefineVerbatimEnvironment`. Within that environment I'd like to `\input{}` files, which works all fine and well until one of them includes a hyphen. Here's an example that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{terminal}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}

\begin{document}

\begin{terminal}
  \input{some-file}
\end{terminal}

\end{document}
```

If I try to `\input{file}` the contents of the file show up in the verbatim environment just as I'd expect. But if I try and `\input{some-file}` I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `more\unhbox \voidb@x \kern \z@ \char `\discretionary {-}{}{}input.tex' not found.
```

Obviously, my hyphen is being translated into `\unhbox ... {-}{}{}` - how can I stop this happening?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: You can't do like this. You need a "verbatim input": `\VerbatimInput{some-file}`

Comment: egreg - if I do this, I get "! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.". This happens whether or not the file name contains a hyphen or not.

I am just replacing \input{xxx} in my example with \VerbatimInput{xxx} - is this what you mean?

Comment: @JohnGraham No, you don't need the `terminal` environment at all.

Comment: Do you need to interpret TeX commands int the input file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move the `-` somewhere safe, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{terminal}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
\newcommand\somefile{\input{some-file}}
\begin{document}

\begin{terminal}
  \somefile
\end{terminal}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David - I went for a slightly more flexible form of the above, adding a new command: `\newcommand{\hyphenate}[2]{#1-#2}` used like so in my terminal environment: `\input{\hyphenate{some}{file}}`.

Answer (score 1):

It mostly depends on what you want to input, but either if you need to interpret TeX commands in the input file or not, `\VerbatimInput` seems the way to go:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{v-inp.sh}
#!/bin/env bash
echo "${PATH}"
exit
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{v-inp.tex}
\textcolor{red}{abc}def
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\VerbatimInput{v-inp.sh}

\bigskip

\VerbatimInput[commandchars=\\\{\}]{v-inp.tex}

\end{document}
```

Note that your construction

```
\begin{terminal}
\input{\hyphenate{v}{inp.sh}
\end{terminal}
```

would not give the expected result break. On the other hand, if you want to input a TeX file, treating it as "almost verbatim", you just need the `alltt` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
\expandafter\input\expandafter{\detokenize{v-inp.tex}}
\end{alltt}
```

will work as well. You can define a better command:

```
\newcommand{\vinput}[1]{%
  \expandafter\input\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}%
}
```