# How to include contents of file as verbatim?

Tags: verbatim, input

How can I include the contents of a text file in my latex document as verbatim?

I tried (the text file does not contain any @)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}   
    \verb@
    \input{temp.txt}
    @
\end{document}
```

but I get the error: `\verb ended by end of line.`

PS: of course the above cannot work even without the error, because if it worked the output file would just contain the single line `\input{temp.txt}`

Comment: Your best bet is to use `fancyvrb` as discussed in [Using \input in a fancyvrb verbatim environment - problem with hyphens](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95220/28808).  This isn't exactly a duplicate of that one, but I'm sure there is a question that covers this exactly.

Comment: Alternatives could be [`moreverb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moreverb), [`verbatim`](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim), or [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [another package from CTAN topic verbatim](http://ctan.org/topic/verbatim). Even [`alltt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/alltt) could be enough.

Comment: ...also the `verbatimbox` package offers options here.

Comment: By all means, take a look at section 6 of the user guide of the [fancyvrb](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb) package, "Writing and reading verbatim files". In paricular, do familiarize yourself with the `\VerbatimInput` macro , which takes one argument -- the name of the file whose contents are to be included in verbatim mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\verbatiminput{temp.txt}
\end{document}
```

I use this regularly to include `TeX` source, so lots of unusual characters are handled properly - i.e literally.